# Finding the identify a web application is impersonating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, com

Is there a way to find out what identity an MVC web application is impersonating?

I've set web.config to include

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
```

For IIS7 in integrated pipeline mode, I believe this should make the application impersonate IUSR (my thinking is set out in my blog post [Identity impersonation with IIS and ASP.NET](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/October-2011/Identity-impersonation-with-IIS-and-ASP-NET.aspx).

The MVC application itself uses Forms Authentication, and I can see the logged in user ok at

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

But my application then has to call a COM component, and I need to be sure what account it is using.  From my tests, it still seems to be using NETWORK SERVICE, rather than IUSR, so I'm looking for a way to verify which identity the application is impersonating when calling the COM component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User`